# Can I get a secured XML file from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, authentication

Hi I wanted to know if it is possible to get a secured XML file from an AJAX call.
I have the following code to get the xml file (which works):

```
   function loadXMLFile() {
       var filename = 'test.xml';
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: filename,
           dataType: "xml",
           success: parseXML,
           error: Fail
       });
   }
```

With secure I mean that people can not get the xml file through their browser.

Comment: An Ajax request *is* "through their browser".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to write JavaScript that will tell the user's browser how to get some data without also making that data available to the person who controls the browser.